# dotdotdot jquery plugin for dynamically created html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dotdotdot

I am creating elements using:

```
$(sel).append("html");
```

I need to apply the dotdotdot plugin to this dynamically created html (which has the class "ellipsis"), but it doesn't seem to go into effect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ellipsis").dotdotdot({
    ellipsis    : '... ',
    watch: "window"
  });
});
```

How do I apply the plugin to dynamically created html?

EDIT:

This is working now, but I have another problem. I can see the element's text overflow before dotdodtdot is applied for dynamically created elements. Is there a way to fix this?

Trying to remove "visibility: hidden;" after it its loaded in the callback, but it also does not seem to work:

```
/*css*/
.invisible {
   visibility: hidden;
}

//js
$(".ellipsis").dotdotdot({
    ellipsis    : '... ',
    watch: "window",
    callback: function() { $(".ellipsis").removeClass("invisible"); }
});
```

Comment: Apply dotdotdot after the element is added inside DOM. Use the callbacks.

Comment: I call dotdotdot after the element is appended with no visible effect.

Comment: Not sure what I changed, I think making the dotdotdot selector a <p>, but it looks like it is now working. I think there is a display rule that must be set and p defaults to it.

Comment: Note the earlier comment is before the first EDIT, I still am having issues with the display delay between .dotdotdot() after the element's text has been appended.